# Uninstall nginx on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I was given a server to setup, but this server was not reset, and the provider is quite slow on resetting it, so I have to completely uninstall some stuff it has, one of which is nginx.

I had a few problems when doing setup on my local machine for nginx due to multiple installations of it, so I want to avoid the same mistake now.

Problem is, I have no idea how nginx was installed here, and I need to remove it.

When I access the server through SSH I only have this folder `$HOME/backups/nginx`.

Any idea how to uninstall this?  Whenever I google it only comes up with `apt-get uninstall` and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

> **Problem is, I got no idea how nginx was installed here, and I need to remove it.**

Check if the package manager knows about nginx, if it does, use that package manager to uninstall it.

```
dpkg –l \*nginx*   # lists packages whose name contains "nginx"
dpkg -L nginx      # lists files in package "nginx"
```

See [Sourceforge tutorial](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/tutorials/apt-get-intro/info.html.en)